# Compute the distributional derivative of $1_{B(0,1)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$：$\partial_{j}1_{B(0,1)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Compute the distributional derivative of $1_{B(0,1)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$——$\partial_{j}1_{B(0,1)}$ where $j=1,2$ and $B(0,1)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

My own attempt is: Take $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, we have $\langle \partial_{j}1_{B(0,1)},\varphi\rangle=-\langle 1_{B(0,1)},\partial_{x}\varphi\rangle=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}1_{B(0,1)}\partial_{x}\varphi dxdy=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\partial_{x}\varphi dxdy=\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(\sqrt{1-y^{2}},y)-\varphi(-\sqrt{1-y^{2}},y)dy$,

What should I do next? Thanks! any suggestion are welcome!!!

Comment: write the result as an integral over the boundary of the ball.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but can you give me a relatively detailed description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\langle \partial_j1_{B(0,1)},\phi\rangle&=-\langle 1_{B(0,1)},\partial_j\phi\rangle\\\\
&=\iint_{B(0,1)} \hat x_j\cdot \nabla \phi\,dS\\\\
&=\hat x_j\cdot \iint_{B(0,1)} \nabla \phi\,dS\\\\
&=\hat x_j\cdot \oint_{\partial B(0,1)} \hat n \phi\,d\ell\\\\
&=\oint_{\partial B(0,1)} \hat n_j\phi\,d\ell\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} (\hat x_j\cdot\hat r)\phi(1,\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \delta(r-1)(\hat x_j\cdot\hat r)\phi(r,\theta)\,r\,dr\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

So, in distribution, we see that

$$\partial_j 1_{B(0,1)}=\delta(r-1)\hat x_j\cdot \hat r$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{x}_{j}$? Thank you!

Comment: Those are unit vectors.   $\hat n$ is a unit vector normal to $\partial B$ and $\hat r$ is the radial unit vector, which in this case is also normal to the boundary of $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Best wishes!!!

Comment: You're more than welcome.  It was my pleasure to help.  Happy Holidays!